# Using Javascript in lightbox Button

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

I'm looking for a way to get a light-box window to close after submitting the information.

Now if that wasn't enough; I am also looking to have a light-box refresh it's parent page.

Now that you know how needy I am I'll show what I have for myself right now.

My JavaScript for the update query button:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function close_and_refresh(){
    //Reload The Parent Page
    opener.location.reload();
    //And then Close the Entry Page
    close();
}
</script>
```

The button I have assigned:

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" onclick="close_and_refresh();" />
```

I thought it would work, but it proved not; if anyone knows how this would be accomplished it'd be great.

Comment: it looks like you mixing some concepts here. If you're using something like a litebox then there is no such thing as an 'opener' object. You can only call 'opener' if you're using an actual popup window, which can then communicate with its parent, the 'opener'. Also, 'close()' (and I guess you mean 'window.close()' here) implies you're inside a separate (popup) window.
Also, doing a location reload would mean that posting the form will be cancelled and your SQL query associated with the form will not get executed

Comment: Then yeah; I have to rethink my entire concept. Not really proficient with javascript in the very slightest. I had the reload parent and close in my query php. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: what are you showing in the litebox? a layer within your page or a separate page in an iframe?

Comment: Its a seperate page within an iframe

Answer (score 0):

Change Input type submit to input type button

```
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="close_and_refresh();" />
```

Comment: Changed it to button type, but still not having any luck; now it's also not running the SQL query associated with the form.

Comment: are you sure you use window pop ?

Comment: I'm using Lytebox for the actual form pop up which brings up a new window; the window is actually a javascript page.

Comment: can you include your HTML so I can understand batter

Comment: I can't think of what HTML you are wanting me to include. I think what you would actually want to see is the lytebox.js file, but I won't post that on here as I would be slightly irritated to see so much code thrown into an issue that I don't think it would be fair to anyone. I'm thinking there has to be a way to Close the window and refresh the parent just by using javascript here. If you go to lytebox.com you can view the source there, but like I said. I'm not going to throw that much code onto an issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Once the form has been submitted, within the litebox iframe, you can let the iframed page writeout some javascript that calls a function in the parent document.

A very basic setup would be something like this:

in the parent javascripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeLitebox() {
        // close your litebox
    }
</script>
```

in the iframe page, after successfull submitting:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.closeLitebox();
</script>
```

do a Google search for something like 'calling parent from iframe', there's loads of samples available...